# Did the Romans eat fish on Fridays in honor of Venus?

Tags: ancient-history

I heard that the ancient Romans ate fish on Fridays in honor of the goddess Venus and that the early Christians co-opted this practice in order for the converted pagans to keep it. And that’s why many Christians do eat fish today. Is this accurate? Did the ancient Romans ate fish on Fridays in honor of Venus? Here are some sources I have found but they don’t cite any footnotes or sources:

> The ancient Celts had associated fish with Venus, the pagan goddess of love, which implied a suspicious level of sinfulness. The situation changed when the rites of the Roman Church were brought to England by the Benedictines and others at the end of the sixth century, when the pagan Anglo-Saxons gradually embraced Christianity. Roman policy was always to replace pagan observances with Christian ones, so if followers of Venus ate fish on Fridays, then Christians would eat it on the same day as atonement.
>
> Fagan, Brian. *Fish on Friday: Feasting, Fasting, and Discovery of the New World*. United States: Basic Books, 2006. Pg. 49

> In Greece Aphrodite was eaten sacramentally as a fish. More directly relevant to Western tradition is that fish were eaten on the day of Venus in Rome, in commemoration of the goddess and of the deification of yoni, the female genitals. Devout fish-eating is one of the many pagan customs taken over by the church and given a new interpretation, in this case removing the sexual content. Christian fish-eating signified only the avoidance of animal flesh on the day Jesus was crucified. Friday could just as well have been a vegetarian day had the church not been motivated to co-opt the Venereal fish-feast for the Christian Friday.
>
> Lawrence, R. J. (1991). *The Fish: A Lost Symbol of Sexual Liberation?* Journal of Religion and Health, 30(4), 311–319. Pg. 313

Comment: It's worth remembering that the Romans didn't have a 7-day week.  Their nundinae was 8 days long, the seven day week was middle-Eastern and began to appear during the early Imperial period, primarily from Jewish and Christian sources.  The Wikipedia article on the Roman Calendar may be useful.

Comment: Lawrence doesn't specifically say that the Romans ate fish on Fridays (which doesn't make sense for the reason Mark Olson gave). That Fagan book is just pop history and got this fact wrong.

Comment: @MarkOlson - I know you didn't write a lot, but this seems a legit question, and your comment seems a legit answer to it. Consider writing it as a proper answer?

Comment: @cmw - Same comment/suggestion goes for you.

Comment: "In Greece Aphrodite was eaten sacramentally as a fish" - I wonder the sourse for this. During Aphrodisia, the festival in honor of Aphrodite, fish didn't play any part.

Comment: I've been trying to look for the source for this claim but the only source I've found are some mosaics that depicts Venus as a personification of Friday but they don't show any fish or sea life. Here it is: https://www.theoi.com/Gallery/Z50.1F.html

Comment: Fish was a symbol of abundance in Greek mythology and several goddesses had ponds with fishes in their temples like Artemis in Ephesus. But I never read about Greek religious consumption of fish

Comment: I've read some primary sources but they only said that the Syrians did not eat fish because they thought they were sacred to Venus. Here are the primary sources I've read: https://www.theoi.com/Olympios/AphroditeTreasures.html#Animals

Comment: The funny part is that pseudo-Hyginus is calling her "Venus" doing an interpretatio romana, but the Syrian goddess with sacred doves and fish was Atargatis.

Answer (score 10):

It's worth remembering that the Romans didn't have a 7-day week  Their nundinae was 8 days long, the seven day week was middle-Eastern in origin and began to appear during the early Imperial period, primarily from Jewish and Christian sources.

As far as I can tell, the Republican Romans did not name the days of the week or assign religious significance to them.  Up to the point where Caesar reformed the calendar in 46BC, it was theoretically a lunar calendar -- I will avoid the glorious detail, but you can find good summaries on Wikipedia at [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) and [Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week) -- but was close to chaotic due to political manipulation and inaction.

Days were referred to as "x days before the [Ides, Nones, Kalends] of March".  Holidays were tied to the annual calendar and work days were ordered by an essentially arbitrary scheme. It did not repeat on either a 7-day or 8-day cycle.

While the 7-day week was known as early as 100AD -- Plutarch is known to have written a book on the subject of why the days of the week are named as they are around then, but the book is lost -- Rome did not move officially to a 7-day week until 321 AD when Constantine officially decreed a seven-day week in the Roman Empire, including making Sunday a public holiday.  (There was a *very* complicated system of days being designated with one of seven designation to say what could be done by the Republic on that day: Courts open, public assemblies possible, filing of lawsuits possible, etc.)  ((One sometimes wonder how Rome conquered an empire when it couldn't manage its calendar...))

There is graffiti from Pompeii mentioning a day of the Sun, but, interestingly, it seems to have been a different day or the week than other attested days of the Sun. (Since the week was not very important, it's possible that different areas used different 7-day weeks right along side the common 8-day nundinae!)

The Wikipedia article on the [Roman Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_calendar) may be useful.

As the Empire went on, the 7-day week gained in importance but at the same time the classical pagan religion lost importance: Long before the triumph of Christianity, Rome had faced the reality that its traditional religion provided little or no emotional or spiritual help for people who were increasingly adopting beliefs that did. The period of the 200s and 300s featured a fascinating attempt by philosophers -- the Greek/Egyptian  [Plotinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotinus) is best known -- to create a synthesis of the classical paganism with Platonic philosophy. (Some of the more interesting intellectual documents from that era were debates between Christians and Neoplatonists.)

Of course strange Eastern customs came to Rome. e.g., Juvenal around 120AD: "Syrian Orontes has long since flowed into the Tiber, and brought with it its language, morals, and the crooked harps with the flute-player, and its national tambourines, and girls made to stand for hire at the Circus." Who knows if he didn't also have a 7-day week in mind?

Bottom line:

- Republican Rome did not use the 7-day week and didn't for the most part organize their calendar that way.
- In later Imperial Rome even the non-Christians and non-Jews would probably not have fooled around with the old pagan gods other than in public rituals.
- It is *very* unlikely that eating fish on Friday for Venus was a common or general practice at any time.
- Rome was big and Rome was full of people of all nationalities and all sorts and, especially in the 1st century might have had Romans adhering to an Oriental cult which ate fish for Aphrodite.
- But I can't say I've ever heard about it.

There. A nice clear, decisive answer.